# Signing an Access database with a trusted code signing certificate

Tags: vba, ms-access, code-signing, ms-access-2013

I have a code signing certificate from GoDaddy.  I've used it successfully to sign the Inno Setup install packages that I use to distribute my Access databases.  I'd now like to use it to sign the Microsoft Access databases *themselves*.  The cert is imported into my Personal Store under both my administrator and non-privileged user accounts.

I tried the following:

- Open an Access database (.accdb, .mdb, doesn't seem to matter)
- go to VBA IDE, Tools --> Digital Signature...
- Click on [Choose...]

I got the error message:

> No usable signing certificates are available. Please insert your smart card, or contact your administrator to obtain a signing certificate.

Did I miss a step?  Is this supported?

Comment: Click the file tab, Save As>>Advance>>Package and Sign

Comment: I should have clarified that I'm using Inno Setup to sign the install packages for my Access databases.  I want to sign the database itself.  The "Package and Sign" process does the same thing as the Inno Setup: it signs the package but not the database inside it.  Microsoft says as much [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Show-trust-by-adding-a-digital-signature-2F6B7D18-A9D3-400D-9F63-9029551E61A1?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1): "*After the database is extracted from the package, there is no longer a connection between the signed package and the extracted database.*"